# stored procedure for creating mysql.user

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, ddl

I'm trying to make a stored procedure which will take two arguments (username and password) and will make a user which has certain grants on a schema. This is what I currently have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `create_admin` (
IN userName VARCHAR(60),
IN userPass VARCHAR(60))
BEGIN

CREATE USER userName@'%';
SET PASSWORD FOR userName@'%' = PASSWORD(userPass);
GRANT DELETE,EXECUTE,INSERT,SELECT, UPDATE ON kairos.* TO userName@'%';
SHOW GRANTS FOR userName@'%';

END
```

However, the password is giving me all sorts of trouble. Whatever I do, I cant seem to stick in the variable into the password field, whether it be using the CREATE USER x IDENTIFIED BY y syntax, or this one. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to use a dynamic query for this

Answer (score -1):

Try below procedure to create user by passing username and pass word as parameter:

First grant access to your user to create user and execute procedure. 'TEST' is the logged-in username to create procedure.

```
GRANT CREATE USER TO TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_admin(
    userName IN VARCHAR2,
    userPass IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  SQLTest VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
  SQLTest := 'CREATE USER "'||userName||'" IDENTIFIED BY "'||userPass||'"';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLTest;
END create_admin;
/
```

Execute procedure to create user:

```
EXEC create_admin('NEWUSER', 'NEWUSER1');
```